# ReduxForm: dispatching 'change' action inside form in FormSection

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I would like to dispatch a change action in a FormSection.

Currently I'm doing this in myForm.jsx:

```
<FormSection name="content">
   <MyFormSection sectionName="content" formName="PanelForm"/>
</FormSection>
```

following this in MyFormSection.jsx

```
import {  change } from 'redux-form';

// my component...

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, props) => ({
   change: (name, value) => dispatch(change(props.formName, props.sectionName+"."+name, value)),
})
```

I don't like to pass down the form both the name of the form and the section.

Would anybody have a better way of doing this?

Answer (score -1):

If you are inside a Redux-Form Input component you can use `this.props.input.onChange(value)`

but if you are just wanting to create a function that when executed changes that value of a form which is not used in a Redux-Form Field Component, I think you are doing it the correct way. Here is another example I did just so you can see. This function was being passed down to a child form through props for one very specific way of changing values in my 'wizard' form.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    changeFormAction: (fieldName, value): void => {
      dispatch({
        type: '@@redux-form/CHANGE',
        meta: {
          form: 'wizard',
          field: `styles.[${fieldName}]`,
          touch: false,
          persistentSubmitErrors: false
        },
        payload: value
      })
    }
  }
}
```